# Multiple images in one frame slider

Tags: jquery, flash, slider

I need to create a slider exactly like in this link: ~link snipped after resolution - the one on the right which is created in flash. It's multiple images in one frame of the slider. Not sure what exactly such a slider is called.

The images in slider in question are coded into the SWF and it's not using XML. I tried a de-compiler. It only lets me edit existing images but doesn't let me insert new images and delete old images. I need to change the images in that slider.

Can I achieve that in jQuery? If yes, how? If not then how to do that in Flash? I don't have much knowledge of jquery and have no knowledge about Flash.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The slider used there is http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

Comment: Not the slider on the left but on the right with multiple small images. I am talking about the one made in flash.

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

Comment: Guys, please leave the left one. I am talking about the slider on the right. There are TWO sliders.

Comment: Yes...i have given right side e.g.

Comment: Create 4 instances of e.g & they will flash like charm..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for DynamicDrive.

dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/index.html

dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

Do this for 2nd e.g. but you have to take care this four divs to align as you want them.

```
<div id="fadeshow1"></div>
<div id="fadeshow2"></div>
<div id="fadeshow3"></div>
<div id="fadeshow4"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Anup! Thanks but I am not talking about the slider on the left. I am talking about the slider on the right. There are two sliders. Please look carefully. The slider on the right is created in Flash. I need to add new photos to it.

Comment: Can I have 4 images in 1 rather than displaying 4 sliders?

Comment: ok...you can keep this as last option, if you didn't get anything, then go for it...!

Comment: OK. Thanks. Since I didn't get any other solution I've marked your solution as correct.